# In Spark windowing, how do you fill null for when the number of rows selected are less than window size?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

assume there is a dataframe as follows:

```
machine_id  | value
 1| 5
 1| 3
 1| 4
```

I want to produce a final dataframe like this

```
machine_id  | value | sum 
 1| 5|null 
 1| 3| 8
 1| 4| 7
```

basically I have to do a window of size two, but for the first row, we don't want to sum it up with zero. It will just be filled with null.

```
var winSpec = Window.orderBy("machine_id  ").partitionBy("machine_id  ").rangeBetween(-1, 0)
df.withColumn("sum",  sum("value").over(winSpec))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag` function, add *value* column with *lag(value, 1)*:

```
val df = Seq((1,5),(1,3),(1,4)).toDF("machine_id", "value")
```

---

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val window = Window.partitionBy("machine_id").orderBy("id")

(df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)
   .withColumn("sum", $"value" + lag($"value",1).over(window))
   .drop("id").show())

+----------+-----+----+
|machine_id|value| sum|
+----------+-----+----+
|         1|    5|null|
|         1|    3|   8|
|         1|    4|   7|
+----------+-----+----+
```

Comment: How would you generalize the solution for window size larger than 2?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a general solution where **n** is the size of windows

- Spark- Scala

```py
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
    
    val winSpec = Window.partitionBy("machine_id").orderBy("machine_id").rowsBetween(-n, 0)
    val winSpec2 = Window.partitionBy("machine_id").orderBy("machine_id")
    df.withColumn("sum",  when(row_number().over(winSpec2) < n, "null").otherwise(sum("value").over(winSpec))
      .show(false)
```

- PySpark

```py
    from pyspark.sql.window import Window
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *
    
    winSpec = Window.partitionBy("machine_id").orderBy("machine_id").rowsBetween(-n, 0)
    winSpec2 = Window.partitionBy("machine_id").orderBy("machine_id")
    df.withColumn("sum",  when(row_number().over(winSpec2) < n, "null").otherwise(sum("value").over(winSpec))
      .show(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `rowsBetween` rather than `rangeBetween` api as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
var winSpec = Window.orderBy("machine_id").partitionBy("machine_id").rowsBetween(-1, 0)
df.withColumn("sum",  sum("value").over(winSpec))
  .withColumn("sum", when($"sum" === $"value", null).otherwise($"sum"))
  .show(false)
```

which should give you your expected result

```
+----------+-----+----+
|machine_id|value|sum |
+----------+-----+----+
|1         |5    |null|
|1         |3    |8   |
|1         |4    |7   |
+----------+-----+----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: How would generalize the solution for window size larger than 2?

Comment: in the above case window size is 3 and not 2. We are just considering the sum function to be applied over two rows at a time, -1 means from previous row to 0 means to current row.  And what do you mean by generalize?